# AWS Lambda Trigger Not Activated for Large File Uploads to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I've developed a system where uploads to an S3 bucket trigger an AWS Lambda function. This Lambda function is supposed to execute a script hosted on ECR, which does not depend on the uploaded file's size or content. The system works as expected for small files (tested with .xlsx and .png), activating the Lambda function without any issues.

However, when I upload larger files (video files and others), the Lambda trigger does not activate. I've tested this with file sizes of 30MB, 50MB, 100MB, and 200MB, but only the 2MB file successfully triggered the Lambda function.

Here are some specifics about my setup:

- The Lambda function is triggered by an S3 event. The function's
  execution does not depend on the file uploaded;
- it performs a generic    task unrelated to the file content or size.
  I have confirmed that IAM    policies and permissions allow for the
  Lambda to be triggered by S3    events.
- There's no apparent size limitation in the trigger    configuration.
  I'm puzzled as to why the Lambda trigger works    perfectly for a
  small file but fails for larger files, despite the    fact that the
  Lambda's task does not require interacting with the    file itself.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or could provide insight into why this might be happening? Tks